# Database Design for Form Builder

Tags: architecture, database, database-design, relational-database

Hi guys I'm trying to create Form builder in my app for different Events that have happened and publish them, so the users can fill them out.

Little About Logic:

Forms are created per different Event that has happened, and then users can popuplate and view them

As for the database I'm using Postgres.

Here is how my current models look:

**Form model:**

```
form
-----
  id (PK)
  name
  user_id (FK to users.id)
```

**Form Element**

```
form_element
-------------
  id (PK)
  form_id (FK to form.id)
  element_type_id (FK to element_type.id)
```

**Element Type** (could be text_field, radio, dropdown)

```
element_types
-------------
  id (PK)
  name
```

**Element Values** (Stores Values inputed by User)

```
Form Element value
===============
    id (PK)
    element_id (FK to form_elements.id)
    user_id (FK to user.id)
    value
```

The **form** is populated with **form_elements** that reference the forms. And has a relationship 1 to many (one form has many fields). **element_types** is used so they know which type they are. **element_types** will store a list of different elements a form can have. Types could be: "text_field", "drop_down_list", "radio_buttons", "checkbox".

Now I have few questions about my Database Design ?

1. **Form Element** model and **Element Type** model should have 1 to 1 relationship ?
2. How should I create for example type **Dropdown** where would I store additional fields for Dropdown options in a new field, in a new Table, how would I design that ?
3. **Element Values** table should be *Many to Many*, should I have to store user_id per Field valoue or could i have somehow bind it to Form ?

Comment: 1. Is 1..n relationship. Even if it wasn't and you did want 1..1 you would probably just be better off directly putting the name field in the form_element table unless you have a good reason. 2. Many, many ways to do this. I would just make new tables which have fk field to relevant form elements 3. Unclear what it is you want, but if these are values submitted by other users then no, you need to store that reference somewhere. As of now it could only be considered a n..n relationship from one user to another user (via element_id.form_id.user_id). Consider making an ERD.

Comment: @ZombieTfk Hi thank you so much for answering :)